# it may/can be worn over the shoulder

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider these definitions of "may", given in https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/may

**Definition 3**: You use **may** to indicate that something is sometimes true or is true in some circumstances.

*a) A vegetarian diet **may** not provide enough calories for a child's normal growth.*

*b) Up to five inches of snow **may** cover the mountains.*

*c) ...families that **may** have both parents working.*

**Definition 6**: You use **may** when you are mentioning a quality or fact about something that people can make use of if they want to.

*d) The bag has narrow straps, so it **may** be worn over the shoulder or carried in the hand.*

*e) Some of the diseases of middle age **may** be prevented by improving nutrition.*

My questions are:

1) Are these usages of "may" common in speech and in writing?

2) Could we use "can" in place of "may" in all the examples under definitions 3 and 6 except example a)?

Comment: All except (a) and (c), I would say.

Answer (score 1):

The usages aren't uncommon.
You shouldn't use "can" in example e), for the same reason as in a). It expresses much more certainty than "may".

For example b)

> Up to five inches of snow may cover the mountain.

you could use "can" if speaking of climatic possibilities in general, but not in the case of today's weather report. For that, you have to stick with "may".

You can't use "can" in example c) with the same meaning.

Only in example d) is the meaning of "can" the same as that of "may".

Comment: **you could use "can" if speaking of climatic possibilities in general**--- I think that's what definition 3 in the OP says: *You use "may" to indicate that something is sometimes true*.